# Changing downloaded themes

Tags: theme

I have a "simple" question. I've tried to google it but without success. I've recently downladed a custom theme from the magento site. Now, I have changed my CMS pages to this new theme, but where can I change the skin for my wihlist, my account, my cart? when I enter in it it automaticaly changes back to the default magento theme. Please help..

TNX

Answer (score 1):

After installation of your theme you need to activate it in System>Configuration>Design

Click on the Themes and enter you theme's name in the following fields:

Templates
Skin (Images / CSS)
Layout
Default

Your theme name is the name of the folder that is in app/design/frontend// ( can be 'default' in your case)
You can find [screenshots here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/enabling-your-new-theme-in-magento)